# IP address classification?

Tags: router, ip, ip-address

I was reading about IP address classification recently and I have a doubt regarding it.

The range for `class C` IP addresses is *192.0.0.x-223.255.255.x.*

So whenever I buy a new router,the IP for router configuration is something like *192.168.x.x*

My Question is that,does the company which manufactures the router has to pay for using Class C addresses?

or If I were to manufacture the routers myself,will I be allowed to use the Class C IP range for hosts.

Can I create a router with Class A IP addressing ?.

Comment: Classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes. Please let them rest in peace. Routers do not have any particular IP address range. A routers interface networks are what you configure on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about classes. They were overruled by CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing) in 1993.

The router vendors usually put the address of the device in the range *192.168.X.X*

It is configured in that way because there are three ranges defined in [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) for **private** use:

```
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255

172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255

192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255
```

Anyone is free to use any address of these ranges in their private network as long as it **remains private**.

Your home router uses NAT to avoid exposing your **private** addresses to the **public** internet, but yet be able to connect to internet.

The following image from a [web site that explains NAT](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/227-nat-concepts.html) may help you to understand the concept.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of network addresses that are known as [private addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) 192.168.x.x is one of them.

The Private address space is:

> 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255- Class A
>
> 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 Class B
>
> 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 Class C

These addresses can be used in a private network, nobody pays for these addresses.

Yes , you can create a class A private address in the range of

> 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255

Comment: Network classes were deprecated in 1993, probably before you were born, and a couple of years before the Internet went commercial. Please forget about network classes because they are not used, and they simply confuse.